# How to chain Angular.JS promises in a loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to design a function in javascript that makes requests to POST multiple items to the database. I then have to take all the data that has been returned and run another `$http` query to the database.

This is my code as it stands

```
var current_request=null;
var workorders=[];
$scope.submit_work_order=function(){
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.parent_jobs.length;i++){
         addPartAndWorkOrder(equipment_id,part_number,work_order,_id);  
    }

    if(current_request!=null){
        current_request.then(function(){
                    if(workorders.length>0){
                        $http({
                            url:'/api/salesorders', 
                            method: "POST",
                            data: {'workorders':workorders}
                        })
                    }
        });
}

function addPartAndWorkOrder(equipment_id,part_serial_number,work_order_id, job_id){
    //part_serial_number
        var info;

        info=$http({url:'/api/parts', 
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {'equipment':equipment_id});

        if(current_request==null){
            current_request=info;
        }
        else{
            current_request.then(function(){
                return info
                });
            });
        }
        current_request.then(function(data){
            return $http({
                url:'/api/workorders', 
                method: "POST",
                data: {workorder_id:work_order_id, part:data._id,job:job_id}
            }).then(function(data){
                workorders.push(data._id);
            });
        })

}
```

What I need is to populate the array `workorders` by running the HTTP requests in the code.

Then I need to run the final run another request to the endpoint `api/salesorders/` with the data from the array

#### TL;DR

This is the way the endpoints should run

```
parts->workorders->parts->workorders->salesorder
```

This is the way they do run

```
parts->salesorder->workorders->parts->workorders
```

I tried to keep adding to the `.then` but as it currently stands its still failing

Comment: you want to use `$q.all()` see $q docs. Basically would allow the first group to all complete before sending the next group

Comment: I've answered below, but I would add that this API design ought to be reconsidered - I've explained why in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break down your calls into dependency tree. It seems that your call pattern must by like so:

```
parts(1) --> workorders(data1) --> _id1
                                        \
parts(2) --> workorders(data2) --> _id2--> salesorder([_id1, id2, _id3])
                                        /
parts(3) --> workorders(data3) --> _id3
```

So, individually, `parts-->workorder` must be done sequentially, but all of them can be done in parallel to each other.

Here's how this can be done (I'm omitting specific API calls and parameters for brevity):

```
function submitWorkOrder(){
  var parent_jobs = [{}, {}, ]; // this is your array of jobs (however you get it)

  var partsAndOrdersPromises = [];

  parent_jobs.forEach(
    function(job){
       var promise = postPart(job).then(postWorkOrder);
       partsAndOrdersPromises.push(promise);
    });

  var allPartsAndWorkordersPromise = $q.all(partsAndOrdersPromises);

  return allPartsAndWorkordersPromise.then(postSalesOrder);
}
```

The `postSalesOrder` will look like so:

```
function postSalesOrder(workorders){
   // workorders is an array of results of each workorder call

   return $http.post("/api/salesorder", ...);
}
```

**OFF-TOPIC:** If you have control over your server API, you should consider creating a single API and post all of the info to create parts, workorders, and salesorder at the end as a transaction. It's not a good idea to have an API call for each, and ofcourse, it does not preserve transactional integrity (e.g. `/api/salesorder` might fail, but you have already submitted the previous orders)

Comment: Yep. I know it does make sense to do that. (the API change). Thanks for the answer